# how to implement a refresh button with React Hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to implement a refresh button but can't get it done.

This is how my code looks like:

```
// ParentComponent.js
const ParentComponent = () => {
  const { loading, error, data } = useItems();

  return (
    <ChildComponent items={data} />
  );

  ... rest of my code that shows the data
};

// ChildComponent.js
const ChildComponent = ({ items }) => { 
  return (
    // Logic that renders the items in <li>s
    <button onClick={() => console.log('Clicking this button should refresh parent component')}
  )
};

// services/useItems.js
const useItems = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(API_URL + '/counter')
      .then((response) => {
        setItems(response.data);
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setLoading(false);
        setError(error.message);
      });
    }, []);

    return { loading, error, data: counters };

}
```

I've tried several ways but none did the work. any helps would be truly appreciated :)

Comment: As a part of refresh, do you wish to fetch data again? Idea to solve your issue: Add a callback function in child component and pass a callback from parent component. In this callback, call `useItems` or any processing you need

Comment: Your code looks fine, but your useEffect gets executed only when the component calling the hook gets rendered. Wrap your current useEffect code inside a useCallback, in order to return the refresh fn, and then from the calling component call it mount with a useEffect, and pass it to onClick for refreshing

Comment: Ofc hooks can return functions too. useState is the most basic hook in React which returns also a fn

Comment: P.s. I was suggesting to fetch through axios in a fn that will be exported by hook, not to export useEffect

Comment: @quirimmo My apologies. Might have misunderstood

Comment: what do you mean by refresh here,  call the api again and get data, or refresh the entire page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think `useEffect` is the right mechanism here. Since it's an imperative call, nothing reactive about it, `useState` does the job just fine:

```
// ParentComponent.js
const ParentComponent = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState('');

  const refresh = () => {
    axios.get(API_URL + '/counter').then((response) => {
      setItems(response.data);
      setLoading(false);
    }).catch((error) => {
      setLoading(false);
      setError(error.message);
    });
  };
  useEffect(refresh, []);

  return (
    <ChildComponent items={items} refresh={refresh} />
  );

  // ... rest of my code that shows the data
};

// ChildComponent.js
const ChildComponent = ({ items, refresh }) => { 
  return (
    // Logic that renders the items in <li>s
    <button onClick={refresh}>
      Refresh
    </button>
  )
};
```

Comment: This will not work. You are not loading initial data. Secondly, OP has that part as a non-ui component. You have removed it. What if OP wanted to reuse that part in many components?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the missing initial call to `refresh`. Now it will work.

Comment: You are still missing the part where you need to use a custom hook

Comment: useEffect(() => {
   refresh();
  }, [])
Is a more common approach to run a method on initialisation

https://medium.com/@felippenardi/how-to-do-componentdidmount-with-react-hooks-553ba39d1571

Comment: Finally, I ended up marking this as the answer to my question because of, I tried all th answers here, and this one looks cleaner and works better in my understanding after all. 

Thank you so much for all the support!

Answer (score 1):

There are couple fo small parts where you need to make changes to resolve issue.

1. You need to create a communication for `refresh`

   - Create a function to process any processing for refresh.
   - Pass this as a prop to child component
   - In child component, call it on necessary event, in this case `click`
2. Now since you are using hooks, you need to get it invoked.

   - You can add a function `refreshData` in your `useItem` hook and expose it
   - Call this function on click of button.
   - You will also have to add a flag in hooks and update `useEffect` to be triggered on its change
   - This function is necessary as `setItems` is only available inside hook.

Following is a working sample:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;
// ParentComponent.js
const ParentComponent = () => {
  const { loading, error, data, refreshData } = useItems();
  const refreshFn = () => {
    refreshData()
  }

  return (
    <ChildComponent
      items={data}
      onClick={refreshFn}/>
  );

  // ... rest of my code that shows the data
};

// ChildComponent.js
const ChildComponent = ({ items, onClick }) => { 
  const onClickFn = () => {
  console.log('Clicking this button should refresh parent component')
    if(!!onClick) {
      onClick();
    }
  }
  return (
    // Logic that renders the items in <li>s
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={ () => onClickFn() }
      >Refresh</button>
      <ul>
        {
          items.map((item) => <li key={item}>{item}</li>)
        }
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
};

// services/useItems.js
const useItems = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState('');
  const [refresh, setRefresh] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (refresh) {
      setItems(Array.from({ length: 5 }, () => Math.random()));
      setRefresh(false)
    }
  }, [ refresh ]);

  return {
    loading,
    error,
    data: items,
    refreshData: () => setRefresh(true)
  };
}

ReactDOM.render(<ParentComponent/>, document.querySelector('.content'))
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='content'></div>
```

---

As correctly commented by [hackape](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3617380/hackape), we need to add a check for `refresh` and fetch data only if its `true`

Comment: Did you forget to put a if condition inside useEffect callback? `useEffect(() => { if (refresh) { ... } }, [refresh])`. Otherwise when you toggle `refresh` back to false, you’ll trigger another round of re-render, which in turn will re-fetch data.

Comment: @hackape yes. I might have forgotten to do that... Hope it helped though

Comment: Well. I’m not much a fan of this solution, looks over complicated to me.

Comment: Even with the if condition guard, toggling `refresh` back to false inevitably triggers one more unnecessary re-render. Although I agree it’s no big deal since no observable impact, I would say it’s suboptimal at best. But the part I feel uncomfortable is the code style, you introduce unnecessary structs into the code.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple trick is to increase an integer state, let's just call it `version`, which would trigger a re-render of `<ParentComponent />` and if `useEffect` depends on `version`, it'll re-execute the callback, so you get the "refresh" effect.

```js
// ParentComponent.js
const ParentComponent = () => {
  const [version, setVersion] = useState(0)
  // when called, add 1 to "version"
  const refresh = useCallback(() => {
    setVersion(s => s + 1)
  }, [])

  const { loading, error, data } = useItems(version);

  return (
    <ChildComponent items={data} refresh={refresh} />
  );
};

// ChildComponent.js
const ChildComponent = ({ items, refresh }) => { 
  return (
    // Logic that renders the items in <li>s
    <button onClick={refresh} />
  )
};

// services/useItems.js
const useItems = (version) => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(API_URL + '/counter')
      .then((response) => {
        setItems(response.data);
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setLoading(false);
        setError(error.message);
      });
    }, [version]);  // <-- depend on "version"

    return { loading, error, data: counters };

}
```

Comment: This is interesting, I didn't think about this option. Although I think @Rajesh answer seems to be more appropriated for my case. Will give it a try in another component though, thank you!

Comment: Well, I gave it a proper read and find Rajesh’s answer is essential same to mine. Main diff is I use an integer, he uses a boolean. But I found his solution a bit flawed. See my comment under his answer.

Comment: I'm gonna try your solution now, but it makes me wonder... is what I'm doing a good way to work with React Hooks? Should I use another method instead? is this the way how it should be done?

Comment: I have to agree both our approaches are similar and yours look cleaner, however in my opinion, a component should not depend on external stuff. It should rely on its own state. Depending on external value means you are exposing details of your implementation. Ideally a component should be declarative. So I'm my example, you call a function and that's it. That becomes simpler when someone consumers your code. But it maybe just my opinion

Comment: @MatiasSeguel I find Christian Fritz’s answer most appropriate to your case. His reasoning is also solid. My way works but logically it looks hacky. Fritz’s both works and looks cleaner.

Comment: @Rajesh “component should not depend on external stuff” excuse me I don’t get what you’re referring to by this comment. Care to elaborate? In my code I don’t see neither ParentComponent nor ChildComponent depending on any external stuff.

Comment: Thank you so much @hackape and Rajesh. Both of you helped me out figuring out how my code should looks like and work. I ended up choosing Fritz's answer. Though, you guys did help me a lot.